# Certificate authentication over socks/ssh

Tags: ssh, certificate, socks-proxy, socks

My workplace has the requirement that to browse any internal site the browser has to present a valid certificate. My desktop at work has such a valid certificate. I would like to tunnel to the desktop via ssh and use socks to browse company internal web sites from home. I can set up the ssh tunnel and enable dynamic forwarding. What does not work is presenting the right certificate. It should be possible to present the work desktop certificate when browsing from home (because that is the machine that is actually getting the web pages). How do I do this?

Comment: What web browser or other HTTPS client are you planning to run on the work machine? Or is that the advice you're looking for?

Comment: google chrome or firefox.

Comment: Ah, I had originally misunderstood part of what you are trying to do. Now that I get it, I need to point out that SOCKS won't work for this, as it merely forwards your traffic without getting involved in TLS. So nothing on your work machine (that is, nothing with access to your TLS user cert and its matching private key) would be involved in the TLS authentication, so your work TLS user cert would not be presented to your work's internal web servers. You might be able to do this with an HTTPS proxy, just not a SOCKS proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You could try (if you are only going to a single internal site) setting up a TCP proxy that makes a SSL/TLS connection upstream.  [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) will allow you to do this, and also allows you to specify a client certificate to use. Then you would SSH in, and connect to that proxy instead of the internal server (you may need to edit hosts file so you can still specify site by name so that the http host header is filled out correctly).

[image: WinGate TCP mapping with client cert]

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate.